# string starting with specific pattern

Tags: regex, r, string

This is very simple R question but I could not find an answer.

I would like to find strings starting with a specific pattern.
e.g. if I have the pattern 
`"ABC`
and I would like extract strings starting with `ABC` in the following vector 
`c("ABCGDFGFD","WWABC","AYBC")`

Expected result for this example: `TRUE FALSE FALSE`

NB: The length of the pattern is not always 3 characters as in this example. It could be longer or shorter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regex is simpler in this case:

```
grepl("^ABC", x)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

The caret `^` special character identifies the beginning of the line. No need to have to specify the amount of characters to count to.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `substr` for this:

```
test <- c("ABCGDFGFD","WWABC","AYBC")

substr(test, 1, 3) == 'ABC'

[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If it needs to be longer or shorter, you can change the arguments in substring from 1 and 3.  With 1 and 3, it starts at the beginning of each string, and looks up to, and including, the third character.